# Delete dual boot one partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, 18.04

04 and ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot ,16.04 is older one now i want to delete that OS and use only 18.04 (installed on /dev/sda7  )and 18.04 installed on /dev/sda1  .How i can delete ?if i delete 16:04  is there posibility to  face problem of GRUB ?please suggest on this

```
ubuntu18@ubuntu18-Latitude-3460:~$ sudo df -h

[sudo] password for ubuntu18: 

Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
udev            5.8G     0  5.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.2G  2.0M  1.2G   1% /run
/dev/sda7        85G  7.4G   73G  10% /
tmpfs           5.9G   56M  5.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
tmpfs           5.9G     0  5.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs           1.2G   16K  1.2G   1% /run/user/121
/dev/loop0       91M   91M     0 100% /snap/core/6350
/dev/loop1       35M   35M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/818
tmpfs           1.2G   76K  1.2G   1% /run/user/1000
/dev/sda6       222G  143G   69G  68% /media/ubuntu18/756afa92-311a-4ee6-98ab-bd6cd0d66caa
/dev/loop2      141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/74
/dev/loop3      2.3M  2.3M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/260
/dev/loop4       13M   13M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/139
/dev/loop5       15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/45
/dev/loop6      3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/57
/dev/loop7       92M   92M     0 100% /snap/core/6531
/dev/loop8       54M   54M     0 100% /snap/core18/782
/dev/loop9      1.0M  1.0M     0 100% /snap/gnome-logs/57
/dev/loop10     4.2M  4.2M     0 100% /snap/gnome-calculator/352
/dev/loop11     3.8M  3.8M     0 100% /snap/gnome-system-monitor/70
/dev/loop12      15M   15M     0 100% /snap/gnome-characters/206
/dev/loop13      36M   36M     0 100% /snap/gtk-common-themes/1198
/dev/loop14     144M  144M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-28-1804/23
/dev/loop15     141M  141M     0 100% /snap/gnome-3-26-1604/82
/dev/sdb2       465G  100G  366G  22% /media/ubuntu18/Backup
/dev/sda1       141G   17G  117G  13% /media/ubuntu18/ec184ce3-0c41-45f9-9267-a82e9f91d999
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Run this on your ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub
```

Remove the old Ubuntu 16.04 partition from Ubuntu 18.04 using gparted or any tool you want.
Then without rebooting your system update your grub (only to be safe) with

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda && sudo update-grub
```

If something goes wrong you can always boot a live ubuntu from a cd/usb and Install and run Boot-Repair.

then click "Recommended Repair".

Nothing that complex.

Comment: Update of grub only updates menu. You need to run the `sudo grub-install /dev/sda` then run the `sudo update-grub` from the install you want to be default boot.